# Source control and compilation tool chain

Tags: version-control, builds

I am a single developer working on a large system.  I was recently informed that there may be an opportunity to recruit another developer or maybe two.  I have incorporated source control into my approach using Subverison and Tortoise SVN.

I was talking to another developer who I used to work with recently and he reminded me about the concept of a compilation tool chain and specifically nightly builds for unit testing.  I have two questions:

1. Is it good practice for all software development teams to use unit testing and nightly builds? Is there any criteria that identifies teams that are more suitable than others for nightly builds.
2. How do developers identify areas suitable for unit testing? I assume that you look at the use cases.  I assume that these use cases could include different processing methods e.g. users interacting with a web application or a batch processing job that runs via a scheduled task each night.

Comment: On a not entirely relevant note, Git and Mercurial provide very nice workflows for multiple developers, especially when compared to subversion. But frankly just start using some source control... fast

Comment: @jozefg: Sounds like he already is.

Comment: Can you split this into two separate questions?  One does not really have to do with the other, and the first one needs some work; it's attracting answers like "CI is good, just use it, m'kay?"  Make it more specific to your issue at hand.

Comment: @RobertHarvey He explicitly mentioned SVN

Comment: @jozefg So? ...

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm mentioning DVSC since they tend to play better with multiple devs and no server

Comment: @jozefg - you just can't use SVN properly, it **is not much worse** in team-work, than (any) DVCS, in **most (!!!)**  aspects

Comment: The world has moved beyond nightly builds. Read up on [continuous integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, continuous integration is a good practice for any project. For very small projects, the infrastructure required for continuous integration may be an overkill, but this doesn't apply to small projects done within a large company: a large company should already have the required infrastructure, and adding a small project to it shouldn't be too difficult.

As for unit testing, you have to take decision yourself:

- Larger projects are better suited for unit testing than smaller ones,
- Business-critical projects are better suited for unit testing than projects which don't do anything critical,
- Projects which follow practices like code review of all new code, formal reviews, etc. need less unit testing than projects which are not.

Side note: the fact that you waited until other developers were added to your team before starting to use version control is disturbing. You're expected to use version control for any project, including the one where you work alone.

Comment: @downvoter: feel free to comment about what's wrong with my answer, so I can improve it. Simply downvoting isn't helpful neither for me, nor for the community.

Answer (score 1):

In short: Yes, **using builds generated by a build server as well as unit testing are good practice** for every project.

Using a build server to generate your continuous and nightly builds will benefit you greatly. I would consider it good practice for every project [among other continuous integration practices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration). Ideally, there is no difference between continuous and nightly builds, but this depends on the project size. You may think that your developer computer already acts as the *integration environment*, which is true and may be sufficient for small-scale projects. But imagine revisiting the project again in the future. It will always be helpful if you have your integration environment stored in some VM where it does not interfere with all the other projects that you have done. Your **tool chain is configured correctly in that environment** and nothing broke just because you had to update some tool. Just use it again, whenever you need it and be sure that the project works in the environment that it is targeted for. Also, you will always **have your builds in once place** not scattered over your personal machine. They are ready to be tested continuously as well. So this is somehow a *prerequisite* to testing every commit which in turn ensures that you catch errors early.

As for **testing**: A project so small that it does not have a good architecture might be hard to test, so *size of the project* influences the ability to test. However, most modern languages already come with a set of standard test tools and there are [some principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) that help you design your application in a way that it is easy to test. Unit testing might be easier than testing the entire system, however you should always have system tests covering your use cases.

Comment: You haven't convinced me of the crucial nature of CI.  Looking at the CI Wikipedia, it seems that CI is mostly needed to insure code merges happen properly, a problem that is completely eliminated by proper planning and exclusive checkouts of individual files. The Wikipedia also states that developers check out an entire branch of code to work on.  Why?  Why aren't they working on individual files, and checking them in when they're done?

Comment: @robert Harvey,  are you against ci? Your comment suggests that developers should checkout individual files rather than entire projects. Are you saying that ci is not necessary if individual files are checked out?

Comment: @w0051977 Doesn't sound like you disagree in principle with my statement.  I spoke with the folks in the C++ room, and they say that CI doesn't really have much to do with code merges, so.  I was just hoping for a better answer, that's all.

Comment: @robert Harvey, are you able to post an answer as you sound knowledgeable about the subject area?

Comment: @w0051977: No.  I'm not qualified.  I came here to become enlightened, and was disappointed.  I've voted to close the question as too broad (see my comment on the question).

Comment: The answer should specifically target the need to use a build server to keep your tool chain in check (this will benefit you if you have multiple projects building on your developer machine). Also, as the question was geared towards testing as well, the builds generated by that machine always use the same environment which is a prerequisite for running tests repeatedly. This will give you the freedom to tweak your developer machine whichever way you want without having to risk breaking the build/test.

Answer (score 0):

> he reminded me about the concept of a compilation tool chain and specifically nightly builds for unit testing

Nightlies for unit-testing?! WTF?! It's totally unrelated things

Back to questions

> Is it good practice for all software development teams to use unit testing

Yes

> and nightly builds?

Irrelevant and conditional-specific. Unit-testing implies a) automatic b) full coverage c) in-house d) formal testing of the whole products (ideally, with CI - after **each change** in codebase), nightlies - a) manual checks b) with less frequently c) by external testers d) mostly only some - widely used or recently fixed - functionality of product

> Is there any criteria that identifies teams that are more suitable than others for nightly builds.

Mass products, targeted on *deeply different* user's systems (which can't be easy reproduced in developer's environment), *may be* better tested by users in every-day usage

> How do developers identify areas suitable for unit testing?

Nohow, **Unit Testing** must test all and any operations, performed by product by testing elementary blocks of product

> I assume that you look at the use cases

No, it's **Functional Testing**, where you test *how it work*, in Unit Testing you perform more low-level test "Will it work?" "Will it work always?" "Does all rare-cases catched?" etc